# Can't get standard deviation to work in C

Tags: c, math, standards, deviation

I tried everything to get standard deviation to work.
I'm trying to make a program that gets grades of students (count decided by user) and it calculates the mean of the grades and also the standard deviation. It calculates the mean fine but for standard deviation it gives "7712160851427328.00"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    int j;
    int count;
    int grade = 0;
    int grades[5] = {0}; //Init
    int sum = 0;
    float deviation_sum;
    float mean;
    float standard_deviation;

    printf("Give Count: ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("Give %d grade: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &grade);

        switch(grade){
        case 0:
            grades[0]++;
            break;
        case 1:
            grades[1]++;
            break;
        case 2:
            grades[2]++;
            break;
        case 3:
            grades[3]++;
            break;
        case 4:
            grades[4]++;
            break;
        case 5:
            grades[5]++;                                   
        }
        sum += grade;
    }

    mean = sum/count;
    printf("mean: %.2f \n", mean);

    for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        while(grades[i] == 0){
            i++;                
        }
        for(j = 0; j < grades[i]; j++){
            deviation_sum += (i-mean)*(i-mean);
            printf("%d,%d\n",i,j);
        }   
    }

    standard_deviation = sqrt(deviation_sum /count - 1);
    printf("deviation: %.2f\n", standard_deviation);
}
```

I think the problem is in the last for loop just can't figure it out.

Comment: First tip: you can replace the entire `switch` statement with `grades[grade]++`.  Second tip: Don't use two variables named `grades` and `grade` unless you want to make yourself cry.

Comment: What will be output of your code, after correcting all the logical errors pointed out in different answers, if I give input `0` to `count`?

Comment: Even entering `1` might be interesting.

Comment: Wow, 4 answers each pointing out 4 different issues that are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to initilize deviation_sum to zero. Otherwise it takes garbage value as its initial value

Answer (score 3):

Your mean calculation will fail as you are doing integer division, and this will then make the subsequent std dev calculation incorrect.

Change:

```
mean = sum/count;
```

to

```
mean = (float)sum/count;
```

so that the division is performed using floating point arithmetic. You might also want to print the value of mean at this point to check that it looks reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Also this

```
standard_deviation = sqrt(deviation_sum /count - 1);
```

shall be

```
standard_deviation = sqrt(deviation_sum / (count - 1));
```

Please [see here for the background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid this type of construct (`i` could cause array access out-of-bounds):

```
for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
      while(grades[i] == 0){
         i++;                
      }
```

Use `if` instead of `while` and use `continue` to loop over again.

For correcting the error you are getting, do following changes in your code (I am just giving you hints)
 1. Use **typecasting** where necessary
 2. Monitor variables (especially array indices) for proper bounds
 3. When using functions like `sqrt`, do check for positivity of the argument otherwise you may face `Domain ERROR`.
 4. Always remember to initialize variables when required.

I would also suggest **a task** for you:

> > Try removing your `switch` with a simpler logic.